# Can't disable WSGIErrorOverride

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I am backing a web app with a Flask API that returns custom error codes. The API runs through Apache and the WSGI module, in daemon mode.

I included a `WSGIErrorOverride Off` instruction in the Apache `conf` file for the API (which is supposed to be the default but I included it anyway).

Yet anytime my Flask app returns a custom error code (they work when I run the app using the built-in server), Apache sends an error 500. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Are you sure that your application isn't crashing when you try to return a custom error code? Check your server's error log.

Comment: @duskwuff You're right, it actually works fine when I set the status code myself (_e.g._ `return "Hello World", 401` in a Flask view). What happens here is that my security package (Flask-JWT) throws an Exception which is somehow captured by Flask when running the built-in server, but not when running in Apache+WSGI. From what I see in the stack trace, it is possible that another package, Flasf-RESTful, is to blame. I'll try bypassing it later tonight.

Comment: You can verify what is actually coming out of your WSGI application using https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Tracking_Request_and_Response That will tell you for sure if the 500 error page is coming from your application. As you said, Apache/mod_wsgi shouldn't be touching your response. Apache/mod_wsgi should only generate a 500 error page if something went wrong in Apache or mod_wsgi, or your response itself was somehow broken, although I can't even think of where mod_wsgi might do the latter.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton that's very helpful. The error 500 occurs before Apache WSGI comes into action as you suspected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comments by [duskwuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091904/cant-disable-wsgierroroverride?noredirect=1#comment50200765_31091904) and [Graham Dumpleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091904/cant-disable-wsgierroroverride?noredirect=1#comment50203035_31091904), I found that the problem doesn't come from Apache WSGI but from my Flask app.
More precisely, I was using the Flask-RESTful package, which is in charge, among other things, of transforming my views' return values into actual responses.

When those views are decorated (here with an equivalent of `@login_required`), those decorators are called by the Flask-RESTful package itself, and when an exception is thrown, something goes wrong.

For some reason, my app returns the custom error when I run the built-in server and an error 500 when I run it over Apache. Not quite sure why yet, I'm guessing Flask-RESTful is doing something that is not WSGI-compliant. I was on the verge of dropping it anyway for other reasons, so I'm OK with this solution.

**Update**: it looks like the problem does indeed come from Flask-RESTful: https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/372